# Who is the Third Umpire?

Tags: cricket, officiating, terminology, icc

For an international cricket match, there should be a TV umpire, a Match referee, and a Reserve umpire along with two umpires on the field,

Who is the third umpire of the above?

What are the responsibilities for each of these umpires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **third umpire** is none other than the TV umpire. His duties include:

- Checking replays and different camera angles to determine if the batsman has made his ground in close run-out decisions that the on-field umpires cannot determine with their naked eye in real-time.
- The same procedure is followed for stumping decisions.
- When a batsman is dismissed, the third umpire checks if the delivery is legal or a no-ball due to overstepping.
- To check a catch is cleanly taken when catches are taken inches off the ground.
- To check if the fielder has touched the boundary line when he slides/catches the ball centimeters away from it.

The decision of the third umpire is either relayed over the big-screen or is communicated via a walkie-talkie to the on-field umpires.

The **Match Referee** has no active role to play during the game. His duties include:

- Observe the game from the sidelines and ensure that the ICC code is followed.
- Make decisions and fine players for improper conduct after going through the umpires matc report.

The **Fourth Umpire/Reserve Umpire** is on stand-by in case the on-field umpires or the third umpire are not in a position to perform their duties due to various reasons. His duties include:

- Take over as third umpire in case the on-field or the third umpire is not able to do so. The fourth umpire takes over as the third umpire and the third umpire replaces an on-field, if an on-field umpire cannot continue.
- Bringing a set of new balls in case of a replacement is required to the ball in play.