# Can the third umpire overturn a decision without being referred from the field?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating, icc

In cricket, one of the officials is the third umpire. Usually, they deliver a decision only when there is a referral from the on-field umpires or from a team in UDRS. Can the third umpire give or overturn an umpire decision without being asked?

For example, the field umpire calls and signals a no ball, and it is known to the third umpire that it is a fair delivery. In a situation like that, do the laws or regulations give authority to overrule the field umpire's call without referral?

Can they contact the field umpire and reverse the decision when it is clear the decision made by the field umpire is wrong?

Comment: The third umpire does not exist in the [Laws of the Game](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/) - which competition are you referring to?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I am asking about cricket. ODI, Test or T20I. Can the TV umpire reverse the decision of the field umpire without being referred when he knows it is a wrong decision taken.

Comment: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2011/who-is-the-third-umpire?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third umpire may initiate contact with the on-field umpires, and potentially give decisions, in only a few limited circumstances.

They invariably involve an incident that was not noticed or acted on by the on-field umpires.

All references and quotes are to ICC Men's Playing Conditions, and are currently identical for all three forms of the game.

> **Appendix D, 2.3.5**  The third umpire may initiate contact with the on-field umpire by two-way radio if TV coverage shows a boundary line infringement or incident that appears not to have been acted upon by the on-field umpires.

and

> **Appendix D, 2.6.4**  The third umpire may initiate contact with the on-field umpire by two-way radio if TV coverage shows the ball to have been in contact with any part of the camera or its cables above the playing area as envisaged under this paragraph.